# how to install web client in windows server 2012

Tags: webclient, windows-server-2012

I don't know how to install web client service on windows server 2012.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: N.B. This installation requires a reboot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enable the desktop experience to get this work in the server OS.

So: server manager > Add Features > User Interfaces and Infrastructure > Desktop Experience

Comment: On Windows Server 2008 R2, it's listed in the root of the feature list (there is no User Interfaces and Infrastructure tree).